# match any character except forward slash

Tags: regex

I'm parsing data from my satellite box to receive music information to display on my iPad. One particular string I'm interested in looks like this;

```
"title": "\"Free Falling\""
```

I want to match Free Falling only so that it can be displayed. 
I tried

```
"title": "(.*)"
```

but it returns `"\Free Falling\"`

I tried negating the forward slashes `[^\/]` but the when tested, the first space between Free and Falling matches the entire pattern

How do I match the words Free Falling only, without the quotes and forward slashes and retain the white space?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is it in JSON?

Comment: Try this `"title": "\\"(.*)\\""`.

Comment: Thank you, revo. Yes, it's JASON. I tried testing all of the responses in a regex tester and none of them match. I'll try it in my software when I get home and see if they work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the syntax is always same and such title string starts and ends with `\"`, then use a regex pattern

```
"title":\s*"\\"(.*)\\""
```

and your desired result will be in group #1

---

If the `\"` is optional, then use

```
"title":\s*"(\\"|(?!\\"))(.*)\1"
```

and your desired result will be in group #2

Comment: Thanks, Omega. Yes, the syntax is exactly the same for all song titles received from the device. "\(.*)\"

Answer (score 0):

If other entries do not have these additional `\"`s around the title names and you want to be able to use one regex to match titles both with and without `\"`s, you can use a regex like this:

```
"title": "(?:\")?([^\\"]*)
```